# System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:51156/.well-known/openid-configuration&#x27

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have generated a token using JwtSecurityToken, however, when I have added it to request header in postman to call an action in my api, I encounter this exception:

> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:51156/.well-known/openid-configuration&#x27;. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
>    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.&lt;GetAsync&gt;d__3.MoveNext()&#xD;&#xA;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

This is how I generate tokens: (for the sake of simplicity, I have hard-coded some values temporarily instead of reading from appsettings.json)

```c#
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult RequestToken([FromBody] TokenRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Username == "Jon" && request.Password == "123456")
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.Username)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_securityConfig.Key));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "http://localhost:51156/",
                audience: "http://localhost:51156/",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
            });
        }

        return BadRequest("Could not verify username and password");
    }
```

And this is how my ConfigureService method is:

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:51156/";
                options.Audience = "http://localhost:51156/";

                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
    }
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint comes from OIDC, which you're not using in your example. Rather than setting the `Authority` in your call to `AddJwtBearer`, you need to set the `IssuerSigningKey` on the `TokenValidationParameters`. [Here](https://wildermuth.com/2018/04/10/Using-JwtBearer-Authentication-in-an-API-only-ASP-NET-Core-Project)'s a blog post on the subject.